# How to make asynchronous read of a file with IOCP?

Tags: c++, iocp

I have faced an implementation problem. I am puzzled on how to implement IOCP. I have read a lot on the Internet about it, but still missing one step.
So far what I have learnt is as follows:
In order to use IOCP:

1. on an init function:

```
CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 0); // to have a max thread number available
handler = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED , 0);
CreateIoCompletionPort(handler, NULL, 0, 0); // to associate my handler with an IOCP
```

2. on a read funcion I can do sth like that:

```
ReadFile(..., &Overlapped); // this will return error == ERROR_IO_PENDING which is what I want - asynch read
```

3. now I have difficulties to understand next steps. Should I spawn a thread after ReadFile and wait inside that thread until GetQueuedCompletionStatus is true?

Comment: I am not sure, if IOCP is what you want here. To map the file into memory could be the better choice.

Comment: I want to have simultaneous I/O requests against a single device (file). As far as I understand IOCP is used for that

Comment: Thank you. I do appreciate your input on this question. However I asked how to use it, not what to do instead. I want to learn the IOCP on a simple example to know how to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer for my question is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/680416/2788176

> In very simplistic (and a little over-simplified) terms, you tell the
> IOCP about the IO jobs you want done. It will perform them
> asynchronously and maintain a queue of the results of each of those
> jobs. Your call to tell the IOCP about the job returns immediately (it
> does not block while the IO happens). You are returned an object that
> is conceptually like the .NET IAsyncResult ... it lets you block if
> you choose to, or you can provide a callback, or you can periodically
> poll to see if the job is complete.

IOCP implementation can be found in windows SDK.